# how to create id sender button inside button in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming.I have taken one button inside that, I have created another button programmatically with id sender ,I want to use multiple buttons inside that id sender button using tags.Now I did some coding but it is showing some Exception.When i am giving `[self somemethodname:(id)sender];` here I am getting problem, actually `[self playOrPause]` this one I have used in another button.How to slove this please any body tell me.
Thanks

```
- (void)playOrPause
{
    UIButton *aa = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
    [aa addTarget:self action:@selector(play:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSLog(@"hi iam 2");
    [self play:(id)sender];
}
-(void)play:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *instanceButton = (UIButton*)sender;
        instanceButton.tag++;
        if (instanceButton.tag == 1) 
        {
            NSLog(@"hi");
        } else if (instanceButton.tag == 2) 
        {
            NSLog(@"hi2");
        } 

  }
```

Comment: why you write this method [self play:(id)sender];, you want to call this method after press button?

Comment: what about the `frame` and `addSubView` property of aa button????

Comment: Acctually [self playOrPause] this one i have used in another button

Comment: in your playOrPause method you dont clerify  the tag of the button which will respond to the action(call).so play: method cant decide which block(block of if segment) to respond.

Comment: you can't call this method like you did it here : [self play:(id)sender];, call it like     [self performSelector:(@selector(play)) withObject:<Your sender tag> afterDelay:<Your time interval>];

Comment: [self playOrPause] i have given in (UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

Comment: you juse set tag in [self play:(id)sender]; this method

Comment: @user1796298: what actually is your requirement ?

Comment: Acctually want play song when i pick image in photo gallery.Eacha nd every image i want play different songs that why i want use tag button

Comment: Now what issue are you facing then ? @user1796298

Comment: (UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: inside this i have given [self playOrPause] ,inside that method i want  play song.after that if i pick another picture means its playing same song i want play another song.

Comment: @user1796298: just remove id sender in this -(void)play:(id)sender and selector(play) or else u can do other thing...

Comment: if i remove id sender.Output is not coming,its showing some Exception

Comment: remove the id sender both in the " -(void)play:(id)sender " && "[aa addTarget:self action:@selector(play)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];"write like this and check this will work

Comment: if i remove that id sender means its working but iam not able to play multiple song

Comment: if i use tag means it will work i had tried that but for that we need id sender